# NULL doesn't match template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

I declared a template class  `threadBinaryTree` and a function

```
void threadBinaryTree<T>::inThread
     (threadBinaryTreeNode<T>*root,threadBinaryTreeNode<T>*& pre)
```

but complies error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘threadBinaryTree<char>::inThread
      (threadBinaryTreeNode<char>*, NULL)’|
```

`pre` need to be initialized as NULL, how should I do?

Comment: Have you tried ``nullptr``? ``NULL`` isn't c++ as far as I know.

Comment: From the signature in code,  pre must reference the existing pointer.

Comment: @Jonas `NULL` is in C++ because it is in the C stdlib. `nullptr` is preferred though because of better overload resolution behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second argument takes a non-const lvalue reference to some kind of pointer, but you are passing an rvalue (NULL). You cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. You need to pass an lvalue:

```
threadBinaryTreeNode<T>* p = NULL;
x.inThread( somePtr, p );
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is `threadBinaryTreeNode<T>*& pre` so you can not pass `NULL` to it.

```
threadBinaryTreeNode<T> *empty = 0; // Pass empty to the method instead of NULL
```

Also, it's better to use `0` and `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your second argument to your function is a non-const reference you need to supply a variable, something like this

```
threadBinaryTreeNode<char>* ptr = NULL;
inThread(..., ptr);
```